# How to prevent Firestore to create root collection automatically during addDocument?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore, I have a collection "form1"

In my client app, when I create a document in a collection that doesn't exist, say "form2"

`db.collection("form2").addDocument(data: data)...`

I see from Firestore console, "form2" was created automatically to hold the new document. I hope `addDocument()` would  return error in this case.

How to do it with Security rules? or with other method?

Here is my current Secuirty rules:

```
rules_version = '12';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {  // only logged-in user can access
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Why can't following work? (insufficient permission even if the root collection exist)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /{collection}/{document} {
      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(collection));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disallow writing to all documents as default and then write rules to allow the only ones you decide:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;// This disallow write and read for all documents
    }
    match /admin_/** {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
}
  }
}
```

This will not allow writes to any collection or document except to admin

Comment: my question is exactly HOW to disallow write when a root collection doesn't exist. Your answer does not provide how.

Comment: There is no way to explicity disallow that. However my code above will get you that exact behavior

Comment: your code does not. please ignore /admin_... stuff. You can read my question again.